# What is a good way to build/execute for-loop Tensorflow graph in parallel?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

```
y = []
for i in range(9999):
  x = ... # build/get sub graph
  y.append(x)
y = tf.stack(x)
```

I am trying to build a Tensorflow Graph that contains multiple separate sub-graph/inputs (independently each other) that I am using a python for-loop to achieve this. (assuming the for-loop can not achieve by tensor operation).
I figure out this part is really slow and I think it is because the python for-loop is not in parallel (process them one by one). I wonder is there solution I can make it parallel (because each sub-graph/input is independent each other and separate)? I wonder change to tf.while_loop can be helpful or any other suggestions?